# CSS Responsive comlumns - aligning text

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, css-float

I can't seem to be able to align text from 2 columns that are next to each other.  The first column only has text while the second column has an image and then text below it which for some reason falls under a slightly different line height and not in balance with the text on the left.

Best explained by actually seeing it but the relevant code is below...
http://goo.gl/Jmq1uI

When I resize the browser to make it smaller, the text gets aligned.  How can I make it always aligned?

```
.one_half {
float:left;
line-height:22px;
margin-right:2%;
width:49%;
margin-bottom:27px;
display:block
}

.one_half_last {
float:left;
line-height:22px;
width:49%;
margin-bottom:27px;
display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to size things things vertically in terms of your typographic scale (imagine horizontal lines spaced evenly aligned with the baseline of every line of text).  In your case, your paragraph line height is 22px.  So we'll use that as our scale and size everything vertically based on that:

Make your margin below paragraphs equal to your line height:

```
p {
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 22px; <---- was 20px
}
```

Make sure your image's height (or that of its container) is equal to a multiple of your line height (i.e.: 22px).

```
img.aligncenter.size-full.wp-image-2803 {
 height: 396px; <------- 18*22, closest to natural rendered height
}
```

**CAVEAT:** This only works if your columns are always fixed-widths, as you can make your image an exact height at each media-query break point.  If your columns are percentage based, and can vary at any window width, unfortunately you're going to have a hard time getting your text to align perfectly everywhere.

A common typographical trick is to make your right column narrower and a render the paragraph format differently (ie.: maybe tighter line spacing, smaller font size, heavier weight, etc.).  This does two things:  It removes your alignment problem altogether, and it can give a sense of hierarchy to the two columns (i.e.: left column is primary, right is secondary), which may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't quite work as the text continue to be misaligned depending on the browser size. I feel like there must be an accurate solution otherwise a lot of responsive websites would have misaligned columns.

Comment: Well it's specifically your image that is causing the misalignment, since it can scale vertically to whatever size keeps it proportional.  If you instead placed the image above the two columns such that is spanned the whole width, your column paragraphs would both start in the same vertical position.  As long as the vertical margin of the paragraphs is equal to a multiple of your paragraph line height, the text should always align.

Comment: OK I figured out what is going on with your alignment issue... Even though you had set the height for the image to 396 using the attribute, that is overridden by the flexible image rule (`height: auto; max-width:100%`).  So the rendered height is actually less.  If you explicitly set the height using inline CSS to 396px, the text lines up after you set the bottom padding of the paragraphs to 22px.